# Screen orientation changes in IOS

Tags: ios, screen, orientation

i am new to IOS programming.i create a new single view application with two buttons.its work normal mode but when is rotate the screen it will blank

Comment: post the code, so it could be easy to give solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't enable it for landscape mode. Just go to your project target->deployment info then enable the device orientation for landscape mode. then use this method and mention your button positions there.

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 

if( (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait ) ||(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
{
    // portrait button positons
}

if((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight))
{
    //landscape button positons
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue could that ur not changing frame of your two buttons on orientation. So there are two solution.

1. You could apply autolayout to two buttons and let autolayout handle the position of both buttons.
2. You could programmatically change frame/position of both buttons using following method

   ```
   -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 

   if( (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait ) ||(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
   {
     //Change frame as per **portrait** button positons
   }

   else if((orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight))
   {
    //Change frame as per **landscape** button positons
   }
   ```
3. You could use autosizing also similar to autolayout but not that good to autolayout(feature and usage difference).